# Best resource to learn mediawiki?

Tags: recommendation-engine, mediawiki

Could you recommend some easy-to-follow tutorials on mediawiki?

Comment: Step 1: Run away screaming. (Former MW developer here.) Haha, only serious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used materials given at http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Contents - it was enough to install MediaWiki and to learn basics of articles creating and texts editing.

MediaWiki is actually really simple :)

Answer (score 4):

[Help:Formatting](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting)
[Manual:FAQ](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ)
[Basic Usage](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/mediawiki/)